# Varnish 3.0.7 is caching 404 pages on JPEG that is missing

Tags: varnish-vcl

How can I tell Varnish not to cache 404 pages for JPEG files and retry instead of caching?

Tried this but did not work:

```
if (beresp.status == 404) { set beresp.ttl = 0s; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sub vcl_fetch {
        if (req.url ~ "\.jpeg$" && beresp.status == 404) {
                set beresp.ttl = 0s;
                return(restart);
        }
}
```

A couple of comments/notes. Please treat the above snippet as a "pseudocode" as I have not tested it.

Why retry if 404? Is there a lot of "movement" on your backend(s)?

As another side-note, you should really consider upgrading to Varnish 4. 
Your version is way beyond its EOL.